# What resources are injected automatically by the framework when creating a hosted service?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm struggling to find a documentation about what resources are injected by default into the hosted service `Startup` when building a basic (non-web) hosted service like this:

```
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

            hostBuilder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, serviceCollection) =>
            {
                serviceCollection.AddHostedService<Startup>();

            });

            return hostBuilder;
        }
    }
```

I've managed to figure out that these are injected automatically:

- ILogger
- IConfiguration
- IServiceScopeFactory
- IServiceProvider
- IHostLifetime
- IHostApplicationLifetime
- IHostEnvironment

I've gathered these from various sources and by testing. But where should I look to get a **complete** list of all the injected resources? If the source code is the only alternative I would greatly appreciate some guidance on where to look.

Best regards